# flag not set correctly using .winfo_exists()

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm creating a GUI application using tkinter. I have multiple tabs, and on one of them is a set of radio buttons, allowing the user to choose what they want to input, which is the stored in a treeview. Depending on the radio button the user selects, labels, entry boxes, and a button to add the input(s) into the tree are created dynamically (each radio button requires a different number of inputs and layout in the GUI). All of this works fine. Note that I pre-populate the tree with 1 entry, which the user is to select if they want to add a new entry (this becomes important later).

The issue I'm struggling with is if the user wants to delete or update an entry. I have code which allows them to select an item from the tree and repopulates the correct labels and entry boxes (with their current values). But, I also want to delete the Add button, replace it with an Update button, and also create a Delete Button. I have some code for this too. I use the .winfo_exists() function to determine which buttons are on the screen and set a flag to determine what should be done to set the new buttons.

When I click on a Radio Button everything updates fine. When I click on an existing entry in the tree, everything is also fine. The problem arises if the user clicks on the "New Entry" item in the tree that I mentioned earlier. Every time I click the "New Entry" item, the .winfo_exists() function sees that the Update button exists (meaning it should be replaces with an Add button), but but it returns a value of 0, so my flag is set incorrectly to update the buttons.

I have a ton of print statements to try and follow how the code is progressing, and I can see the flag isn't set correctly, but I cannot figure out why. What am I missing?

Minimal version of the code is below (seems a bit long, but it's as cut down as I can make it). My basic test case is to just add 1 entry to the tree. I click on that entry and everything is fine. I then click on "(new)" and it does not update correctly.

Thanks in advance for the help.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import numpy as np


class MainGUI(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.title('Title')
        self.geometry('750x500')

        # Adds tabs to main window
        self.nb = ttk.Notebook(self)
        self.nb.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=5, rowspan=4, sticky='NESW')
        self.tab1 = ttk.Frame(self.nb)
        self.nb.add(self.tab1, text='Tab1')
        self.tab2 = ttk.Frame(self.nb)
        self.nb.add(self.tab2, text='Tab2')

        # defines a grid 50 x 50 cells in the main window & tabs
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        tab1_r = 10
        tab1_c = 4
        tab2_r = 8
        tab2_c = 4
        for i in range(tab1_r):
            self.tab1.rowconfigure(i, weight=1)
        for i in range(tab1_c):
            self.tab1.columnconfigure(i, weight=1)
        for i in range(tab2_r):
            self.tab2.rowconfigure(i, weight=1)
        for i in range(tab2_c):
            self.tab2.columnconfigure(i, weight=1)

        self.tab1Label = tk.Label(self.tab1, text="This is a Label")
        self.tab1Label.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='NW')
        self.tab1Label2 = tk.Label(self.tab1, text="This is also a Label")
        self.tab1Label2.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky='NW')

        self.types = [('Thing1'), ('Thing2')]
        self.pType = tk.StringVar()
        self.pType.set("Thing1")  # initialize
        col = 0
        for text in self.types:
            self.rBtn = tk.Radiobutton(self.tab2, text=text, variable=self.pType, value=text, command=self.makeWidgets)
            self.rBtn.grid(column=col, row=6, sticky='E')
            col += 1

        self.makeTable()
        self.makeWidgets()

    def makeWidgets(self):
        try:
            for self.label in self.Labels:
                self.label.destroy()
        except AttributeError:
            pass

        try:
            for self.entry in self.Entries:
                self.entry.destroy()
        except AttributeError:
            pass

        try:
            self.addBtn.destroy()
        except AttributeError:
            pass

        try:
            self.delBtn.destroy()
        except AttributeError:
            pass

        try:
            self.updtBtn.destroy()
        except AttributeError:
            pass

        self.Labels = []
        self.Entries = []

        if(self.pType.get() == "Thing1"):
            self.labText = [('Add to Table:')]
        elif(self.pType.get() == "Thing2"):
            self.labText = [('Add to Table:'), ('Also add to Table:')]

        self.xGrid = 1
        self.yGrid = int(np.ceil(len(self.labText) / self.xGrid))
        i = 0
        for j in range(0, self.xGrid + 1, 2):
            for k in range(self.yGrid):
                if(i == len(self.labText)):
                    break
                else:
                    self.label = tk.Label(self.tab2, text=self.labText[i])
                    self.label.grid(column=j, row=k + 8, sticky='SW')
                    self.Labels.append(self.label)
                    self.entry = tk.Entry(self.tab2)
                    self.entry.insert(0, '0.0000')
                    self.entry.grid(column=j + 1, row=k + 8, sticky='NS')
                    self.Entries.append(self.entry)
                    i += 1

        self.addBtn = tk.Button(self.tab2, text='Add Entry', command=self.addEntry)
        self.addBtn.grid(column=self.xGrid + 1, row=self.yGrid + 9, sticky='NSEW')

        self.tree.focus(self.tree.get_children()[0])
        self.tree.selection_set(self.tree.get_children()[0])

    def makeTable(self):
        tab_header = ['Pattern #', 'Description']
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self.tab2, columns=tab_header, height=5, show="headings")
        vsb = ttk.Scrollbar(self.tab2, orient="vertical", command=self.tree.yview)
        self.tree.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)
        self.tree.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=2, rowspan=5, sticky='NSEW')
        vsb.grid(column=1, row=0, rowspan=5, sticky='ENS')
        self.tree.heading(tab_header[0], text=tab_header[0].title())
        self.tree.column(tab_header[0], width=30, anchor='center')
        self.tree.heading(tab_header[1], text=tab_header[1].title())
        self.tree.column(tab_header[1], width=170, anchor='center')
        self.tree.insert('', 'end', values=("", "(new)"))
        self.tree.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.getPtrnTable)
        self.counter = 1
        print(type(self.counter))

    def addEntry(self):
        if(self.pType.get() == "Thing1"):
            self.description = self.pType.get() + ": " + self.Entries[0].get()
        elif(self.pType.get() == "Thing2"):
            self.description = self.pType.get() + ": " + self.Entries[0].get() + " and " + self.Entries[1].get()
        self.tree.insert('', 'end', values=(self.counter, self.description))
        self.counter += 1
        print(self.counter)
        print(type(self.counter))
        self.nominalTableSelect()
        self.repopEntries()

    def delEntry(self):
        treeCnt = len(self.tree.get_children())
        items = self.tree.get_children()
        for i in range(int(self.patNum), treeCnt - 1):
            self.tree.set(items[i], 'Description', self.tree.item(items[i + 1], 'values')[1])
        self.tree.delete(items[-1])

        self.nominalTableSelect()
        self.updateButtons()

    def updateEntry(self):
        pass

    def getPtrnTable(self, event):
        self.item = self.tree.identify_row(event.y)
        try:
            self.patNum = self.tree.item(self.item, 'values')[0]
        except IndexError:
            self.patNum = ''
        self.repopEntries()
        self.updateButtons()

    def nominalTableSelect(self):
        self.tree.focus(self.tree.get_children()[0])
        self.tree.selection_set(self.tree.get_children()[0])
        self.item = self.tree.get_children()[0]
        self.patNum = self.tree.item(self.item, 'values')[0]

    def repopEntries(self):
        try:
            if(self.tree.item(self.item, 'values')[1] == '(new)'):
                self.pType.set("Thing1")
                self.makeWidgets()
                print("Repopulate with New/Blank Entries...")
            else:
                self.thing, junk = self.tree.item(self.item, 'values')[1].split(":")
                self.iNum = int(self.tree.item(self.item, 'values')[0]) - 1
                self.pType.set(str(self.thing))
                self.makeWidgets()  # restore correct label/entry layout
                self.tree.focus(self.item)
                self.tree.selection_set(self.item)
                print("Repopulate with DATA...")
                # some code here to repopulate entry boxes from stored data
        except (IndexError, NameError, AttributeError):
            pass

    def updateButtons(self):
        print("")
        print("")
        print("Update Buttons...")
        print("")
        add = 0
        update = 0
        try:
            add = self.updtBtn.winfo_exists()
            print("Update Button Exists...")
            print("Set ADD flag to: ", add)
        except (AttributeError, NameError):
            print("Update Button Does NOT Exist.")

        try:
            update = self.addBtn.winfo_exists()
            print("Add Button Exists...")
            print("Set UPDATE flag to: ", update)
        except (AttributeError, NameError):
            print("Add Button Does NOT Exist")

        print("")
        print("add = ", add)
        print("update = ", update)
        print("Item to be Checked is: ", self.tree.item(self.item, 'values')[1])
        print("")

        if(len(self.tree.get_children()) == 1):
            print("Nothing in Tree...do nothing.")
        else:
            if(update == 1):   # Add Button Exists - Change to Update
                print("Change to Update Button...")
                self.btnLoc = self.addBtn.grid_info()
                print("Add Button Location: ", self.btnLoc)
                print("Destroy Add, Replace with Update...")
                self.addBtn.destroy()
                print("Add Button Status: ", self.addBtn.winfo_exists())
                self.updtBtn = tk.Button(self.tab2, text='Update Pattern', command=self.updateEntry)
                self.updtBtn.grid(column=int(self.btnLoc["column"]), row=int(self.btnLoc["row"]), sticky='NSEW')
                self.delBtn = tk.Button(self.tab2, text='Delete Pattern', command=self.delEntry)
                self.delBtn.grid(column=int(self.btnLoc["column"]) - 1, row=int(self.btnLoc["row"]), sticky='NSEW')
                print("Update Button Status: ", self.updtBtn.winfo_exists())
                print("Delete Button Status: ", self.delBtn.winfo_exists())
                print("")
            elif(add == 1):  # Update Button Exists - Change to Add
                print("Change to Add Button...")
                self.btnLoc = self.updtBtn.grid_info()
                print("Update Button Location: ", self.btnLoc)
                print("Destroy Update, Replace with Add")
                self.updtBtn.destroy()
                print("Update Button Status: ", self.updtBtn.winfo_exists())
                self.delBtn.destroy()
                print("Delete Button Status: ", self.delBtn.winfo_exists())
                self.addBtn = tk.Button(self.tab2, text='Add Entry', command=self.addEntry)
                self.addBtn.grid(column=int(self.btnLoc["column"]), row=int(self.btnLoc["row"]), sticky='NSEW')
                print("Add Button Status: ", self.addBtn.winfo_exists())


def main():
    MainGUI().mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I'm still not convinced the flag is always being set correctly (using the .winfo_exists() function), I was able to get a working solution. By adding another conditional check to the updateButtons module I check to see if the default "New Item" from the tree was selected, and if so I just repopulate the page with the original buttons for a new entry (using the repopEntries module).

```
def updateButtons(self):
    add = 0
    update = 0
    try:
        add = self.updtBtn.winfo_exists()
    except (AttributeError, NameError):
        pass

    try:
        update = self.addBtn.winfo_exists()
    except (AttributeError, NameError):
        pass

    if(len(self.tree.get_children()) == 1):
        pass
    elif(self.tree.item(self.item, 'values')[1] == '(new)'):
        self.repopEntries()
    else:
        if(update == 1):   # Add Button Exists - Change to Update
            self.btnLoc = self.addBtn.grid_info()
            self.addBtn.destroy()
            self.updtBtn = tk.Button(self.tab2, text='Update Pattern', command=self.updateEntry)
            self.updtBtn.grid(column=int(self.btnLoc["column"]), row=int(self.btnLoc["row"]), sticky='NSEW')
            self.delBtn = tk.Button(self.tab2, text='Delete Pattern', command=self.delEntry)
            self.delBtn.grid(column=int(self.btnLoc["column"]) - 1, row=int(self.btnLoc["row"]), sticky='NSEW')
        elif(add == 1):  # Update Button Exists - Change to Add
            self.btnLoc = self.updtBtn.grid_info()
            self.updtBtn.destroy()
            self.delBtn.destroy()
            self.addBtn = tk.Button(self.tab2, text='Add Entry', command=self.addEntry)
            self.addBtn.grid(column=int(self.btnLoc["column"]), row=int(self.btnLoc["row"]), sticky='NSEW')
```

Any comments on how the .winfo_exists() function or my understanding of it would still be appreciated.